# Does startActivity() always call through to startActivityForResult()?

Tags: android

Does startActivity() always call through to startActivityForResult()? Example:

```
public class ActivityTest extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                    ActivityTest.this, ActivityFoo.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void startActivity(Intent intent) {
        Log.e("hi", "startActivity()");
        super.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
        Log.e("hi", "startActivityForResult()");
        super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
startActivity()
startActivityForResult()
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you check the source?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, because the source code for `startActivityForResult()` looks like this:

```
public void startActivity(Intent intent) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, -1);
    }
```

They wrote it this way to avoid duplicate code. The real implementation of starting an `Activity` is defined in `startActivityForResult()` and if the value of -1 is passed in, it simply ignores results.